# How to set method signature of ScriptMethod in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to create a PSObject method that returns specific type, but it has signature System.Object

How can I forcibly set this to return any other type?

Need solution for PowerShell 2.0 that does not support classes.

```
$o = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $o -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name 'MyMethod' -Value { return 10 } | Out-Null
$o | gm
...
MyMethod ScriptMethod System.Object MyMethod();
```

Requirement 1: Compatible with Powershell 2.0. Native PS classes are unsupported.

Requirement 2: Avoid writing scriptblock logic in .net (c#) and using Add-Type then ( try avoid Add-Type as much as possible, but maybe not completely )

NB: Problem is design-only. There is no problem in converting types. I would like others to see right signature of method, ex, Void or DateTime, etc.

Comment: Why is PowerShell 2.0 compatibility required?

Comment: Because it needs to be applied to few hundreds of W2008R2 servers and W7SP1 clients. There is no way to setup powershell 3 here

Comment: Yes, PowerShell 3 can be installed on Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2.

Comment: As can v4 and v5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/set-up-your-computer-for-windows-powershell/download-and-install-windows-powershell-5-1

Comment: I know that PoSh 3 *can* be installed, but there is no way to do this on hundreds of servers, including the requirement of .net

Comment: I would be surprised if an organization with hundreds of machines didn't have a software distribution tool of some kind. If not, then it's likely worth the investment.

Comment: We have. If someone can guarantee no services will break after changing .net version, this will be good. But there is no such person. That's why we can not update powershell.

Comment: What services are you referring to?

Comment: Damn... Any third party services. When you have few hundred servers that means you have tons of services. Part of them are legacy or garage-made.

Comment: I am trying to understand what a .NET Framework installation has to do with services on the computer. Even in the case where a service uses .NET 3.5, installing a later version of the .NET Framework isn't going to interfere with it. (At least, in my experience, I have never seen that happen.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Well, you never used Microsoft Exchange Server, I think

Comment: Windows versions older than 6.2 (Windows 8/Server 2012) are now obsolete. 6.2 and later have newer versions of Windows PowerShell.